# I am an Indian & have NL RP Type 1. I am travelling from AMS to London City Airport. Next flight is from LHR n 3.5 hrs. Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, europe, transit-visas, eu

I am an Indian & have NL RP Type 1. I am travelling from AMS to London City Airport. Next flight is from LHR n 3.5 hrs.  Do I need a transit visa?
Flight details:
BA8450 from Schiphol to London City Airport
3.5 Hrs halt
VS 302 from London Heathrow to New Delhi Airport

Comment: Check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I already did that and it does provide the information. I have also heard from some friends or other sources who have the Type 1 RP card issue by EEA however they were still quetioned and were denied to go via UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland

If  whatever "NL RP Type 1" supposed to mean meets this criteria than you may not need a Visa.

> Next flight is from LHR n 3.5 hrs.

That appears to be a VERY difficult connection to make. London City to Heathrow is 25 miles with London right smack in between them. If the stars all align, you can make it but I'll give a less than 25% chance.

Comment: I doubt the connection is even possible, they will likely miss the check-in cutoff with a single transport delay

Comment: I will plan to go light (without a baggage...)  and what if we opt via Train to avoid the road traffic...?

Comment: @user131889 You are forgetting check-in deadlines. [Virgin Atlantic's Check-In Deadline](https://help.virginatlantic.com/gb/en/policies/conditions-of-carriage/article-11.html) is **70 minutes before departure**. Thus, to successfully connect to your LHR flight you must leave London City Airport, travel to the correct Heathrow Terminal, find the Virgin check-in desk, and present yourself for check-in **2.4 hours** after your scheduled arrival at London City. Even if everything goes right, I doubt this is possible.

Comment: @user131889 a train journey is still going to take ~90 minutes (maybe get it down to 75 in perfect ideal conditions + timing it right for the express from Paddington).

Comment: @user131889 Train takes anywhere from 1:05 to 1:20 (during the day) but you have to factor in some wait time for the departure.  It's not exactly an impossible connection  but you need a lot of luck. Hence my assessment of "less than 25%". These are NOT odds I would take on a Virgin Atlantic ticket. Keep in mind that if you are late, Virgin Atlantic will simply consider you as a no-show and your ticket may be completely forfeit. You may have to buy a new same- or next-day ticket which will be VERY expensive. Don't risk it.

Comment: LCY is small, and immigration delays are likely not a surprise seeing the size of the building, I would qualify this connection as purely and simply impossible